# forcing scrollbars to appear in listbox

Tags: wpf

Hi can I force scrollbars to appear in listbox when its content do not fit.  I really need it.

To create tabcontrol item I concucted this xaml:

```
 <TabControl.ContentTemplate>

                        <DataTemplate>

                        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
               HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">

                        <Grid Name="RssFeedContainerGrid" >
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="20" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <controls:ucRssFeed Grid.Row="1" RssUri="{Binding FeedUri}" />

                        </Grid>

                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </DataTemplate>

                    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
```

and ucRssFeed contains listbox.

Here some xaml from that control where I want scrolling to take place:

```
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>

                    <DataTemplate>


                    <Grid Margin="10" x:Name="RssFeedCellblock">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>



                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="10" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="0"> 

                                <!-- Topic label-->
                                <TextBlock Cursor="Hand" FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding XPath=title}" Tag="{Binding XPath=link}" Foreground="{StaticResource RSS_Topic_Title}" MouseDown="TextBlock_MouseDown">

                                </TextBlock>
                                <!-- Breakline -->
                                <Line Stroke="{StaticResource RSS_Topic_Title}" Y1="5" Y2="5" X1="0" X2="{Binding ElementName=NewsListBox, Path=ActualWidth}" Opacity="0.7" StrokeThickness="1"/>
                                <!-- publication date label -->
                                <TextBlock  Text="{Binding XPath=pubDate}" Opacity="0.5" />
                                <!-- Description textblock -->
                                <TextBlock FontSize="10" FontFamily="Times New Roman"  x:Name="descriptionTextBlock" 
                                                Text="{Binding XPath=description, Converter={StaticResource HtmlToPlainTextConverter}}"  Margin="10" 
                                                TextWrapping="Wrap" />





                    </StackPanel> 

                      </Grid> 

                    </DataTemplate>

                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

            </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the Height property of your ListBox for the Scrollbar to appear listbox automatically show scrollbar when the content is more